# Optimizing Corsair SSD Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

I am currently having a [Force Series™ GS 128GB SATA 3 SSD](http://www.corsair.com/es-es/force-series-gs-128gb-sata-3-6gbs-solid-state-hard-drive) which is supposed to have the following specs:

Sequential Read Write 560 MB/s sequential read — 535 MB/s sequential write

But, instead, I'm only getting: (which is far less from what it should be doing)

[image]

I already tried to TRIM the SSD with the Corsair Toolbox
and also I have followed this optimizing guide which explains how to improve perfomance by disabling page-file on the SSD and turning off indexing.

Is there anything else I need to do to reach that speed mark?

Comment: The highest real-world benchmark speeds I've ever seen for this SSD are 496MB/s sequential read and 270MB/s sequential write. 467/214 seems about average, so you're just a bit under what other people are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SSD uses a SandForce SF-2200 controller, which only gets the high write performance hwen using data which can be compressed fine. In normal usage the values are much lower (as you can see).

> SandForce controllers also use a proprietary compression system to
>   minimize the amount of data actually written to non-volatile memory
>   (the "write amplification") which increases speed and lifetime for
>   most data (known as "DuraWrite"). SandForce claims to have reduced
>   write amplification to 0.5 on a typical workload. **As a byproduct,
>   data that cannot readily be compressed (for example random data,
>   encrypted files or partitions, compressed files, or many common audio
>   and video file formats) is slower to write.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SandForce#Technology

Comment: So, there is nothing else to optimise in it then?

Comment: correct, there is nothing you can improve here.